# Como criar uma condição que não inclua o mês de dezembro?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou criando uma condiçãoé para ser executada antes do mês de dezembro, ou seja, só executa no período de *janeiro* a *novembro* independente do ano.

```
IF (SELECT TarFechamento FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = @Tarefa) < '01-12-2017'
```

Eu coloquei como se fosse no ano de `2017`, mas quero independente do ano ***2018,2019,2020, etc***

Comment: só usar o month... if month([data]) <12...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187813(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A consulta que você precisa fazer é esta, usando o [month()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) pra saber apenas o mês da data

```
SELECT * FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = @Tarefa and month(TarFechamento) <> 12
```

Comment: show de bola @rLinhares, obrigadao. Ah. Me ajuda naquela outra pergunta, rsrs

Comment: não to podendo entrar no chat.. vou tentar ver de novo aqui, pera..

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais fácil de obter (não) apenas a parte do mês de uma data no SQL é apenas usar a função DATEPART (). Para obter mais informações sobre a função, basta acessar o seguinte link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp.